# Using pyautogui and opencv for screenshot

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am using the following code:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

import pyautogui
import sys


img = pyautogui.screenshot()
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

When I run this, it tells me

```
mat is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

I have tried to use different functions from opencv and it seems they all return the same. What do I need to do in order to take a screenshot then work with it in Open CV?

Answer (score 8):

After some digging, I realise that the pyautogui function is using Pillow which is giving a format that must be adapted to work with opencv.

I added the following code so that it worked:

```
open_cv_image = np.array(img) 
# Convert RGB to BGR 
open_cv_image = open_cv_image[:, :, ::-1].copy()
```

Comment: Something else you could do in order to achieve the same output but more expressive:

`imageObj = pyautogui.screenshot()`

`cv_imageObj = cv2.cvtColor(numpy.array(imageObj),
                     cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)`